# CSS Transform - RotateY not as desired

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I'm using:

```
transform: rotateY( 45deg );
```

and (for the right side)

```
transform: rotateY( -45deg );
```

.. but the result is not as expected, the elements still look like a rectangle. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uy57B/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add perspective:

```
.left, .right {
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    -moz-perspective: 400px;
    perspective: 400px;
}
```

Play with it until you find the right number. Bigger will make the angle seem slighter because the field is deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Use :not. Add a class name to one of your elements and the code should look something like this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
       div:not(.special):hover{
         transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(45deg);
       }
    </style>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="special"></div>
```